# Profiling a clutter-box2d application on ARMv7

Tags: c, profiling, box2d, armv7, clutter

What is the best way to profile and optimize clutter-box2d application on an arm target? 
I have tried using *valgrind* to profile the code on x86 before porting, but it doesnt seem to help. Ported application still runs considerably slow on ARM target.

I wasn't able to get valgrind working properly on arm target to profile and identify bottlenecks.

Used a bit of *Oprofile* but it gives a system wide snapshot and doesnt do much good. Since it does not produce call-graphs.

Answer (score 0):

If all things fail (and you are on a glibc-based system) you can go the traditional route and use gprof to collect profiling data.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gprof

Comment: i tried gprof for a while, but valgrind-callgrind is lot better and would love to get it working on arm. Another problem with gprof is i'll have to recompile all the applications, something i am trying to avoid.